# How can I find a user-supplied string between word boundaries using JavaScript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I have a body of text that I'm searching using JavaScript.  I let the user specify an arbitrary string, then I want to search for that string, with the condition that it is treated as a "whole words", i.e. is between word boundaries.

I just want to be able to say e.g.

```
var userString = "something blah";
// => "blah another thing blah"
"blah something blah blah".replace(new RegExp("\\b" + userString + "\\b"), "another thing"); 

// no match, good
"blahsomething blah blah".replace(new RegExp("\\b" + userString + "\\b"), "another thing");

userString = "something\\blah";

// want to match, but doesn't
"blah something\\blah blah".replace(new RegExp("\\b" + userString + "\\b"), "another thing");
```

As you can see, it breaks down for special characters -- I need a way to tell the RegExp to escape user input, or to set aside a part of the expression as a literal.  Is this possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userString.replace(/([\[\]*+.?{}()\\^$])/g, "\\$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes correctly. To match a single backslash within a regular expression you need to escape it once to have it accepted as an actual backslash within the regular expression. And as you store the regular expression as a string, you need to escape each of those two backslashes again, resulting in `\\\\`. So you can simply escape slashes in your `userString`:

```
userString = userString.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
```

Note that you should sanitize your user input anyway so that people don’t come up with some weird regular expressions that mess up your application.

Comment: Oh I get the sanitizing thing, it's just that I don't want them to be able to use *any* actual regular expression parameters. I need something like a SQL prepared statement, for regexp. I may try tomalak's solution first.